# GAMM using mgcv in R: by participant random effects for categorical variables

Tags: r, categorical-data, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am fitting a GAMM using mgcv. I have two variables, one a categorical 2-level variable **difference**, the other a continuous variable **Learning_stage**. I would like by participant random effects for **difference**, specificly random slopes and intercepts. A stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63726043/gam-with-only-categorical-logical) had an answer saying that factor variables with bs='fs' result in intercepts for every factor level. A smooth function with bs='re' should give random slopes if I am correct.

Would that mean I would need to add the terms s(difference, participant, bs='re') as well as s(difference, participant, bs=’fs’, m=1)?

The model defined so far:

```
model <- bam(error ~ difference + s(Learning_stage) + s(Learning_stage, by=difference) + s(Learning_stage, participant, bs=’fs’, m=1), data=data_for_gamm)
```

Answer (score 4):

You want

```r
model <- bam(error ~ s(participant, bs = "re") +
  s(participant, difference, bs = "re"), data = data_for_gamm)
```

If you want participant random effects and random "slopes" of difference per participant, as per your stated requirement.

The `"fs"` smooths does much more than add random intercepts; it represents a fully penalized spline basis where all smooths share the one smoothing parameter. As it is fully penalized, `s(x, f, bs ="fs")` has a penalty for the constant term in the basis (which means we have a random intercept for each level of the `f`), another penalty for the linear term in the basis (se we have random slopes of `x` per level of `f`), and then a random smooth function of `x` per level of `f`, noting that the `x` in these smooths must be continuous.

The `"re"` basis only gives a random "slope" if you add a grouping variable and the variable you want random slopes for. In your case you have two factors (`participant` and `difference`) but this still works, you'll just get a different estimate of `difference` for each level of `participant`.

If you want a smooth of `Learning_stage`, you have to state what you want that smooth to do. Right now you have a model that asks for:

1. `~ difference` fixed effect for levels of difference,
2. `+ s(Learning_rate)` an average smooth effect of `Learning_rate` (assuming `difference` is a normal factor? If it is an ordered factor, things are different),
3. `+ s(Learning_rate, by = difference)` a separate smooth effect of `Learning_rate` for each level of `difference`. This smooth almost certainly needs `m=1` adding to it to make it more easily identifiable from the "average" smooth effect (2.), and
4. `+ s(Learning_rate, participant, bs = "fs")` a random smooth effect of `Learning_rate` per participant, with smooths sharing the one wiggliness parameter for the smooths. This term also includes random intercepts per `participant` and a random slope of `Learning_rate` as constant and linear terms are in this basis and are fully penalized. You likely don't need `m=1` here.

This is a lot of smooth effects of `Learning_rate`; do you need all of them? There's nothing wrong with the model as you have it, but it is quite a complex starting model.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Difference is a normal factor indeed. I should have been clearer that I would like to ADD the random effects, not just have the random effects, my bad. I am used to "full" models with lme4. I also need the model to "answer" quite some questions, hence the complexity.

Comment: Does the order in s(participant, difference, bs='re') matter? Could it also be s(difference, participant, bs='re')?